# Can I override light blue Selection color with another color?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a form that opens and highlights certain highly formatted rows.
The highlighting is done by selecting those rows, so they are colored light blue.
When the form closes, the rows are still selected, and that's good. The formatting beneath the selection isn't disturbed so if the user clicks anywhere on the worksheet, all the original formatting is intact.

My question is can I select rows and highlight them in a color besides standard blue (bright pink) so the user can see them more easily?  I don't want to have to reformat the interior colors, and then try to figure out how to unformat them when the user is done noticing them.

```
sRowsToHighlight = "196:196,201:201,203:203"
m_wksPST.Range(sRowsToHighlight).Select   ' Turns them blue, but I want a bright color
```

After my code is done, I would want selection to revert to the standard Excel color scheme.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would be surprised if you could do that without manually coding it yourself. The selection colour is an application setting. You could change it in Excel, but that will change it for the whole of excel on that computer (i.e. any worksheets that get opened) and also it wouldn't help if your users are using this spreadsheet on a different computer. But here is a link anyway: http://en.kioskea.net/faq/8703-excel-changing-the-highlighting-color-of-selected-cells